# Angular 1: Defer html rendering after http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular controller I have a http call to a REST service that returns data in a database. This data are shown in a table in the partial view.

It happens random that the render of the html view is done before to get the callback with data, so I see a void table.

Here the code in the controller (I use services for some business logic and to implement the http call):

```
commonServices.find(vm.modelUri, null, vm.filter, function (err, msg, data) {

            if (err || !data.length) {
                $scope.noResults = true;
                return;
            }

            $scope.docs = data; //docs is bind in the view 
            return;
        });
```

Here the service for the http call:

```
function _commonServices(config, $http, $rootScope, $cookies) {
      return {
            find: function _find(modelUri, id, filter, callback) {
                   var url = config.servicesUri + '/' + modelUri;

                   if (id) {
                      url += '/' + id;
                   }


                   if (filter) {
                   if (typeof filter !== 'string') {
                       filter = JSON.stringify(filter);
                   }

                   url += '?filter=' + filter;
                   if (document.cookie) {
                       url += '&' + accessToken;
                  }
                  } else {
                    if (document.cookie) {
                       url += '?' + accessToken;
                    }
                  }

                  $http.get(url)
                    .then(function (data) {
                    //success
                    return callback(null, null, data.data);
                   },
                   function (data) {
                       //error
                      var err = true;
                    return callback(err, data.data.error.message);
                  });
             }
      }
```

}

The find service is used in other controllers and it seems it works good. I would know if it is possible to defer the render of the html table until the data are ready to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of Angular's ng-cloak. It is a directive to prevent the html from being displayed until your angular app is finished loading. Check out the documentation here: [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)